# How to find out unused that disk attached to a server (script)

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, filesystems

I am trying to get unused disk from servers (Looking a script to collect this from multiple servers), It should list only unused disk that not part of any VG / shared disk / cluster (SBD) / oracle ASM etc..

```
testb01 ~]$ lsblk --fs
NAME                     FSTYPE      LABEL UUID       MOUNTPOINT
    sda
    ├─sda1                   ext4              628e7d25-f06e-40b9-a7e1-2cdaf7627446   /boot
    └─sda2                   LVM2_member       qThZDO-rNrI-h5PY-QJXo-Sgpv-LzKN-WtXVha
      ├─vg00-lv_swap         swap              1d5f66c3-909c-41d0-756a-642c7e03b350   [SWAP]
      └─vg00-lv_root         ext4              aa39f8c7-3930-41f1-86cf-d3160d45f04a   /
    sdc
    sdd                      LVM2_member       2JB2ws-UUQC-MQ2v-iumy-4aVK-Ow9K-kicolT
    ├─ldfappvg-usrDEP_lv     ext3              3a90be5b-2e84-f5b7-ac2d-8c3d5cc25b47   /usr/sap/LDF
    ├─ldfappvg-usrtrans_lv   ext3              5037c686-6c1f-87c3-9707-de1e006dc18a   /usr/sap/trans
    └─ldfappvg-sapstage_lv   ext3              8c63e382-cc32-4719-y53a-80a0027ee345   /sapstage
```

Here sdc is unused, but I want to check its part of any other (VG/ASM/SBD)

```
testb01 ~]$ sudo /usr/sbin/pvs | grep sdc
testb01 ~]$
```

But in other server(physical) all disks are in use this disks not have UUID and should not show as free disk.

```
sdb
├─sdb1     vfat               7BL7-1D03                             253.1M     2% /boot/efi
├─sdb2     xfs                64u931ca-92s8-45c5-9g15-qa4fecf3a15a  999.3G     2% /tempfs
└─sdb3     xfs                084l827b-166e-44da-81te-830fec4edcg8    2.4T    61% /data
sdc        mpath_member
└─sbd01
sdd        mpath_member
└─sbd01
```

Please help a script to create a report the disks are actually not in use

Out put like this

```
testb01  - Disk "sdc" size 64G not in use
```

Thanks,

Comment: This isn't a script-writing service. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am trying to find out the disk not in use, with lsblk --fs I can see the disk (not used) with out UUID, but basic disks also with out UUID. I am looks if any one can help on this, command or script. Script writhing service ?, I thought this site, members will help , contribute ..

Comment: It seems like if you were asking for help for scripting before a very first step. Please make a plan of how you put this all together.